# how to get double quotes of a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need double quotes of following variable

```
var foo='bar';
alert(foo);
```

normally I did `alert('foo')`  but I get `foo`...
but i need the answer like this *"bar"* how it is possible in javascript. problem is i am putting `""` around the variable it get foo

```js
var foo = 'bar';
alert("foo");
```

Comment: `alert("\""+foo+"\"");`

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape `"` and alert:

Example snippet:

```js
var foo = 'bar';
alert("\"" + foo + "\"");
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can do this

```js
    var foo='"bar"';
    alert(foo);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use this code:

```
var foo='"bar"';
alert(foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `'x'`, **`x`** can't be `'` character (I mean the basic usage) and the same thing, if you have `"x"`, **`x`** can't be `"`.

**Soulutions:**

**1- Using single-quote inside double-quote:**

```
  console.log("'x'");
```

**2-
You can also print a character by its Unicode, ' Unicode is [`\u0027`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yfce773(v=vs.94).aspx)**

```
   console.log('\u0027\u0027'.toString());
```

**3- escape apostrophes by `\`**

```
 console.log('I\'m JavaScript console.log');
```